# What is this result called: $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=f(c)\int_a^b g(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus

I had a question about Taylor's theorem proof in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867894/remainder-term-in-taylors-theorem/867914#867914):

and the key point in the answer given to me was this:

> there's $c\in(a,b)$ such that
>
> $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=f(c)\int_a^b g(x)dx$$

Can anyone help me identify this rule? Thank you! =)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_integration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mean value theorem for integration. In case you want to know how this name came about:
taking $g=1$, we see that there is $c$ with 
$$f(c)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f \ dx,$$
the right hand side of which is called the integral mean of $f$ over $[a,b]$. (These integrals are fairly important, e.g. because it appears in the Lebesgue differentation theorem; in fact so important that there is even a [standard notation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8aDl.png). Well it should be without the absolute value bars, but somehow no code seems to work here.)

Comment: Thank you for the additional info, appreciate it! =) I am very interested =)

Comment: @jjepsuomi: no problem. I thought I should add some information apart from the name itself.

Comment: @user164074 and a good idea it was ;D thank you! =)